# Image upload: iPhone Client - Django - S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have a general question regarding uploads from a client (in this case an iPhone App) to S3. I'm using Django to write my webservice on an EC2 instance. The following method is the bare minimum to upload a file to S3 and it works very well with smaller files (jpgs or pngs < 1 MB):

```
def store_in_s3(filename, content):
    conn = S3Connection(settings.ACCESS_KEY, settings.PASS_KEY) # gets access key and pass key from settings.py
    bucket = conn.create_bucket('somebucket')
    k = Key(bucket) # create key on this bucket
    k.key = filename
    mime = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
    k.set_metadata('Content-Type', mime)
    k.set_contents_from_string(content)
    k.set_acl('public-read')

def uploadimage(request, name):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        store_in_s3(name,request.raw_post_data)
        return HttpResponse("Uploading raw data to S3 ...")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Upload not successful!")
```

I'm quite new to all of this, so I still don't understand what happens here. Is it the case that:

- Django receives the file and saves it in the memory of my EC2 instance?
- Should I avoid using raw_post_data and rather do chunks to avoid memory issues?
- Once Django has received the file, will it pass the file to the function store_in_s3?
- How do I know if the upload to S3 was successful?

So in general, I wonder if one line of my code will be executed after another. E.g. when will `return HttpResponse("Uploading raw data to S3 ...")` fire? While the file is still uploading or after it was successfully uploaded?

Thanks for your help. Also, I'd be grateful for any docs that treat this subject. I had a look at the chapters in O'Reilly's Python & AWS Cookbook, but as it's only code samples, it doesn't really answer my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django stores small uploaded files in memory. Over a certain size, and it will store it on a temp file on disk.

Yes, chunking is helpful for memory savings as well:

```
for file_chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
    saved_file.write(file_chunk)
```

All of these operations are synchronous, so Django will wait until the file is fully uploaded before it will attempt to store it in S3. S3 will have to complete its upload before it will return as well, so you are guaranteed that it will be uploaded through Django and to S3 before you will receive your HttpResponse()

Django's [File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) documentation has a lot of great info on how to handle various upload situations.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I just checked a couple of other posts and it seems as if the best solution is to upload stuff from the client (iPhone) directly to S3. This will shortcut the server- and won't create double the traffic as far as I can see (i.e. first upload to EC2/Django, then upload to S3).

Comment: Right, the only caveat to what you're talking about is if you do any processing of the images that are uploaded. In my business, each image is resized to a variety of different sizes on the Django server, and each are then uploaded to the CDN. Just an example, but something to keep in mind for your own app.

Comment: I see. So if I don't do processing of the images on the server, then the way to go is Client->S3 directly. If I need to do some processing, I'd go via the Django server. Thanks so much again, this was really helpful.

Comment: That's correct. You could also do post-processing from some sort of service after uploading to S3 from the client, if you wanted to work around that. It would just be more difficult because you would have to query S3 for "what changed since the last time I checked?". Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Jordan. But is it really advisable to go client > s3? I'm just reconsidering this. It appears as if I won't win anything, except having yet another API (the Amazon API) to handle the upload to S3. So it feels much cleaner if I do the upload via the server and then to s3. Has the advantage that I can add an entry to the database straight away (as I need to add an entry for every image I upload). Are there any disadvantages at all if I go client > django/ec2 > s3? It doesn't seem to cost anything to transfer files from ec2 to s3. What would you do?

Comment: What I do with my business is upload to my web server. The file gets stored in temporary storage, and is picked up by a processing service later. I implemented that with Celery. The benefit to that is that my clients don't have to wait around for an upload to complete. The downside is that it adds a layer of complexity. As I mentioned in my previous comment, you could always periodically check S3 to see what's been recently uploaded so that you could add it to your database, if you did want to go straight to S3.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at django-storages. It facilitates storing files on S3 and a bunch of other services/platforms.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I just checked some other posts and it appears as if I should rather upload stuff from the client (iPhone) to S3 directly without going via Django. In that case, I wouldn't need django-storages, I guess. But thanks for letting me know.